# gcd: this name was defined previously and cannot be re-defined

Tags: racket, racket-student-languages

I have to use DrRacket for this problem but every time I run the code, I get this error message "gcd: this name was defined previously and cannot be re-defined". (also I choose the language as Advanced student [custom] in DrRacket. 
below is my code, its a recursive function to find the greatest common divisor:

```
(define (gcd n m)
   (cond [(= m 0) n]
    [else (gcd m (modulo n m))]))

 (check-expect (gcd 0) 0)
 (check-expect (gcd 12 8) 4)
 (check-expect (gcd 6 12 8) 2)
```

Answer (score 3):

The `gcd` function is already provided as part of the Advanced Student language, [as you can see in the documentation here](http://docs.racket-lang.org/htdp-langs/advanced.html#%28def._htdp-advanced._%28%28lib._lang%2Fhtdp-advanced..rkt%29._gcd%29%29). Unlike the full Racket language, the teaching languages do not permit defining functions with the same name as library functions. Note that if you remove your definition of `gcd`, all your tests pass.

If this is homework, then you probably need to name your `gcd` function something else. If the assignment requires that your function be named `gcd`, then there’s probably an issue with the assignment.

Comment: oh yeah changing the name works but now I'm faced with an error function. I changed it to gcd-structural and got this "gcd-expects 2 arguments, but found only 1: expects 2 arguments, but found only 1". I'm so confused.

Comment: Actually you know what I found the problem with the check expect, it can't be 0 or something else. only 2 arguments, so the second check-expect is the correct form. well this tells people of how stupid I get sometimes haha... hey thanks for your help though.